# Pixel Buffer Objects, gReadPixels and GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV

Tags: macos, opengl, driver

I could not get pixel buffer objects to make async glReadPixels work (well it works but has no speed up) on OS X 10.10 with Pixel Buffers using GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER.

I switched from GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE in glReadPixels to GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV

glReadPixels dropped to 0.6 ms from 20ms - in other words it started to work async in a real sense.

My question is:
Will setting GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV as a pixel format work on other mac systems or do I need to test them all?

Comment: using PBOs will be async in any case, the format for this will not matter. It is totally unclear what your problem actually is.

Comment: Using PBO with glreadpixels is async, but glreadPixels takes 20 ms to return with GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and 0.6 with GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV - all when using PBO. So with GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE I lose the value of calling it async, since in the profiler you can see the driver doing the entire call in sync when GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE is on on the intel iris Macbook Pro I am on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be confident that it will perform well on all configurations, you'll have to test them all. It will often depend on the GPU vendor if a certain path is slow or fast. The result can also be different between the drivers for different GPU generations, and can even change from software release to software release.

What you're measuring in this specific example is quite odd. `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` are actually the same format on a little endian machine. There's no good reason why one of them should be faster than the other. It's most likely just an omission when checking if a fast path can be used.

Comment: GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV would be GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE to me (8 bits!). You can see that intel drivers really like that enum... eg http://forums.inside3d.com/viewtopic.php?t=2465